# Subsetting a dataframe with Missing Factors

Tags: r

I have a factor that is missing approx 13,000 levels (there are approx 13,00 missing values / NAs in my factor). How can I subset the data to only include a particular column where the levels are missing?

```
  dat$xyz <- as.factor(dat$xyz)
  subsetdf <- dat[which(dat$xyz == "NA"),]
```

This will return a new dataframe with all original variables with zero observations. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: try this: subsetdf <- dat[which(is.na(dat$xyz),]

Comment: you are welcome. It is an oddity of R that "NA" is not equal to "NA"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, you don't need the `which()`, as the `is.na()` returns a boolean vector. The `which` translates the boolean into a vector of locations of the `TRUE` values.

Try `subsetdf <- dat[is.na(dat$xyz),]`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Sconfluentus

```
  subsetdf <- dat[which(is.na(dat$xyz),]
```